# Editor does not respond after a month of completion of second revision

Tags: publications, phd, paper-submission, editors, elsevier

Our paper underwent a second minor revision after the first major revision. This second revision has been completed by the reviewer 1 month ago, yet the editor has not even seen this report. I know this as the Elsevier tracking status is still "under review" despite the reviewer has sent their report. I am the corresponding author and I sent an email and then my supervisor sent an email but we just got generic responses from the Elsevier Researcher support representative telling us that they have sent a reminder to the editor. yet nothing from the editor. What do we do?

Comment: See the generic/canonical answer: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55665/75368

Comment: You have probably done all you can do.

Comment: How do you know the second review is complete, if the status is "under review"?

Comment: Elsevier lets you track the status of submission. It is under review from the point editor sends the paper to reviewer till they have completed and sent their review. When the editor reads this completed review then only is changes to 'Review complete'.

Comment: So if it still says "under review", then the reviewer could still be working on it and not have submitted their review. No?

Answer (score 1):

Elsevier uses [Editorial Manager](https://www.ariessys.com/solutions/editorial-manager/), for which the status remains as 'under review' until enough reviews are submitted for the status to change to 'required reviews complete'.

Since you're seeing 'under review', the indication is that the reviewer(s) have not submitted their report.

> When the editor reads this completed review then only is changes to 'Review complete'.

This is not correct. When the editor makes a decision, then the status changes to 'decision in progress'. It does not update when the editor reads reviews, and even if it did, it does not update to 'review complete'.